# Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, inflate-exception

I have an application that runs with a navigation drawer and a couple of fragments.
Everything works fine but this one, FragHome, in which I have an image and a ListView.
Pieces of code of my Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home_copia, container, false);
    mStickyView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sticky);
    mStickyView.setText(R.string.sticky_item);
    mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mItemTop = rootView.findViewById(R.id.itemTop);

    LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.top_layout, null);

    mPlaceholderView = v.findViewById(R.id.placeholder);
    mListView.addHeaderView(v);

    mListView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    onScrollChanged();

                    ViewTreeObserver obs = mListView.getViewTreeObserver();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                }
            });

    mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            onScrollChanged();
        }
    });

    // Create and set the adapter for the listView.
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), createListViewData(), R.layout.list_item, new String[] {"item"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
    mListView.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
    return rootView;
}

private void onScrollChanged() {
    View v = mListView.getChildAt(0);
    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

    // This check is needed because when the first element reaches the top of the window, the top values from top are not longer valid.
    if (mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0) {
        mStickyView.setTranslationY(
                Math.max(0, mPlaceholderView.getTop() + top));

        // Set the image to scroll half of the amount scrolled in the ListView.
        mItemTop.setTranslationY(top / 2);
    }
}


/**
 * Function used to create the HashMap needed for ListView item using Simple Adapter.
 * @param key
 * @param name
 * @return
 */
private HashMap<String, String> createItem(String key, String name) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put(key, name);

    return item;
}
private List<Map<String, String>> createListViewData() {
    List<Map<String, String>> itemList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();


    itemList.add(createItem("item","Something");
return itemList;
}
```

Here is the layout

```
<!--suppress ALL -->
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/itemTop"
    android:background="@drawable/home_background"
    style="@style/Item.Top" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="@null"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sticky"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    style="@style/Item.Sticky" />
```

In styles.xml i have those two, Item.Top and Item.Sticky:
TOP:

```
<style name="Item.Top">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">fitCenter</item>
</style>
```

STICKY:

```
<style name="Item.Sticky">
    <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/sticky_height</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:textAppearanceLarge</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#09c</item>
</style>
```

And here is the full logcat trace:

```
05-12 18:01:08.280    8044-8044/it.radonmap.navdrawertutorial E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: it.radonmap.navdrawertutorial, PID: 8044
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:121)
        at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:114)
        at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2387)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17473)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2030)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5845)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at an
```

My home_background in the drawable folder is an image of a 600x400 resolution.
I tried to reduce it to 300x200, I found this workaround searching for a little bit, but nothing changes.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: layout_top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/topTransparent" 
    style="@style/Item.TopTransparent" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/placeholder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/sticky_height" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your layout_top xml?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't more to that stack trace?

Comment: I Think <View ../> making issue remove that and check it

Comment: Added layout_top.xml

Comment: use `ImageView` instead of `View`

Comment: @MickeyTin Which one have I to replace?

Comment: All. ..  . . .......

Comment: @CommonsWare it's exactly like what I posted, truncated after "at an". I believe it's overflowing the max logcat's line number

Comment: @MickeyTin sorry then, that wasn't clear.

Comment: @MickeyTin I tried replacing all `View` with `ImageView` but the same error occurs

Comment: EDIT: I tried debugging and it inflates the view but it crashes on the return statement.